# Google's new denoiser functionality for Google Meet (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1q61B8zdSV0)

Tags: speech-recognition, speech-to-text

wondering if anyone used Google's denoiser for google meet yet? Its just been released.

Sounds cool but wondering if the audio produced (with this 'denoising') will impact ability to auto-transcribe the meeting through an ASR (automated speech recognition).

Most/all of these noise cancellation techniques I've looked at focus on making the speech in the noisy audio signal be more obvious to the human ear.... but they introduce artefacts in the audio signal that mess-up an ASR and any automated meeting transcription .  Would be great if this google denoiser didn't do that.